# Parsing Database string in SQL Select command

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, parsing, select

So basically I have this column called Signature inserted in the database

> Id = 1 
>   Value = John, Micheal, Sara
>
> Id = 2 
>   Value = Mike, Steve, John
>   .
>   .

Now in asp.net I'm not sure how can I do select command and know if the value

John, Micheal, Sara

Has "Micheal" in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer you question:

[CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)() searches for a substring within a larger string, and returns the position of the match, or 0 if no match is found

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE CHARINDEX(Signature, 'Michael') > 0
```

Or

You can just use wildcards in the query (after IF, WHERE or ON):

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Signature LIKE '%' + 'Michael' + '%'
```

But really you should be storing this data in a separate related table.

Answer (score 1):

No. **Don't**.

Add a new table with rows for each signature name, and use a row for each signatory. That is the point of relational databases.

```
1   John
1   Michael
1   Sara
2   Mike
2   Steve
2   John
```

Or better still, add two new tables - one for the signatories, and one for the relation between that and your initial table

```
Signatories

1  John
2  Michael

ItemSignatures
ItemID SignatoryID
1      1
1      2
2      1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from Signature
where value like '%Micheal%'
```

Comment: When posting answers, please add and explanation describing what you changed or added or how it works or something. Even though your answer may be the solution, it's likely that some people who read this don't understand what it means or how it works.